# Python Interpolating time, lat, and lon

Tags: python, interpolation

I am having trouble trying to figure out if python is the best choice for interpolating a data set that I have

```js
**lat   lon    time**
   x1    y1    3:02(t1)
            
       
   x2    y2    3:05(t2)




   x3    y3    3:10(t3)

 
   x4    y4    3:13(t4)
```

I left spaces to emphasis what I am seeking. I'm looking to fill the missing time in 1 second intervals. So I think what I need to do is t4-t1 in order to get 11 equal spaces, converting time to seconds to make calculations easier. Then the graph should look like this:

```js
**lat   lon    time**

   x1    y1    3:02(t1)
   a      b    3:03
   c      d    3:04
   x2    y2    3:05(t2)
               3:06
               3:07
               3:08
               3:09
   x3    y3    3:10(t3)
               3:11
               3:12
   x4    y4    3:13(t4)
```

After this I am looking for the latitude and longitude at each second that I have newly created. So between x2,y2 and x1,y1 I want to find the values of a,b,c,d which will be an interpolated lat and lon.

Is there a way to do this with no consistent values between each set?

Comment: See [this (language-neutral) question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739019/how-to-use-linear-interpolation-estimate-current-position-between-two-geo-coordi) - depending on the speeds you're dealing with, linear interpolation may not be sufficient.

Comment: I recommend checking my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/267004/84004) for doing this over the earth ellipsoid using python

Answer (score 3):

The `numpy` library for python has a function for interpolation built-in. Note that in this example I'm using an integer for the time. You should convert the time into an array of numbers (e.g. seconds) for [numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) to work.

```
import numpy as np

times = [2, 5, 10, 13]
lat = [1.5, 2, 4, 7]
lon = [3, 2, 1, -2]
t = np.arange(2, 14)

latint = np.interp(t, times, lat)
lonint = np.interp(t, times, lon)
for pos in zip(latint, lonint, t):
    print(pos)
```

Should print:

```
(1.5, 3.0, 2)
(1.6666666666666667, 2.6666666666666665, 3)
(1.8333333333333333, 2.3333333333333335, 4)
(2.0, 2.0, 5)
(2.3999999999999999, 1.8, 6)
(2.7999999999999998, 1.6000000000000001, 7)
(3.2000000000000002, 1.3999999999999999, 8)
(3.6000000000000001, 1.2, 9)
(4.0, 1.0, 10)
(5.0, 0.0, 11)
(6.0, -1.0, 12)
(7.0, -2.0, 13)
```

Comment: Thank you Roland! I'm starting to follow a little better. What if I wanted to import a CSV for Lat, Lon, and Time? Would I need to then extrapolate the variables according?

Comment: How would I know? I don't know what is in the CSV file nor do I know what you want to do with it...